# Why gradle could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for a flutter plugin

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, kotlin-android-extensions, flutter-plugin

I wrote a plugin with kotlin, which works as example.
I published this plugin without the example folder.

Now I want to create a flutter app with the public plugin
to test whether others can use the plugin.

I get a gradle error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':allocate_user_apps'.
>
> Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for 8qbsgj5slxel203zipat9627v
>
> (C:\Users\gle.gradle\caches\4.4\scripts-remapped\build_1nm6t3qaagcrhueaws5c4rnfu\8qbsgj5slxel203zipat9627v\cp_proj638c4bcc3be846fd35262b91d5a74869).
>
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'H:\Users\Public\Documents\prog\flutter\flutter_windows_inst.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\allocate_user_apps-0.0.1\android\build.gradle'
>
> (C:\Users\gle.gradle\caches\4.4\scripts\8qbsgj5slxel203zipat9627v\cp_proj\cp_proj638c4bcc3be846fd35262b91d5a74869).
>
> Build file 'H:\Users\Public\Documents\prog\flutter\flutter_windows_inst.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\allocate_user_apps-0.0.1\android\build.gradle'
>   should not contain a package statement.

Where I can search for failures?

Already tried **flutter clean** without improvement

Thanks for advice

Erhy

Answer (score 1):

strange:
in
flutter_windows_inst\ **.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org** \allocate_user_apps-0.0.3\ **android\build.gradle**

I deleted the first line

> package android

and the problem was fixed.

From where was this line is created?

With **modifications** in the **plugin project** I could solve the problem:

In file **settings.gradle** of the plugin project already I deleted the first line
package android

also in the file **build.gradle** of the plugin project already I deleted the first line
package android

I encreased the version number in **pubspec.yaml** of the plugin project

and executed

**cd** to the plugin project base directory

**flutter packages pub publish**

After imported the plugin with the new version number
there was nothing to change in the app project.